# Select random object from an array and change a boolean variable on the selected object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code picks GameObjects with the tag "Coisas" and puts them on a array, then this GameObject gets picked randomly and the it gets printed.

```
    ChangeSprit changeSprit;
    public GameObject player;

    GameObject[] coisas;

    void Awake(){
        changeSprit = player.GetComponent<ChangeSprit>();
    }

void Pick(){
        coisas = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Coisas");
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, coisas.Length);
        player = coisas[randomIndex];
        print (player.name);
    }
```

**What i want to do is to pick a GameObject randomly, and them change a boolean variable inside this other code "ChangeSprit", to true.
But i can't wrap my head around this problem.**

What you guys think the solution could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coisas[randomIndex].GetComponent<ChangeSpirit>().YourBooleanProperty = true`

replace `YourBooleanProperty` with the actual property you want to set to `true`